# get dynamic UIWebview content height of a expand/collapse UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I am loading a `UIWebview` in a expand/collapse `UITableView`. I need to change the row height according to the `UIWebview` content height. if i set the `UIWebview` delegate in the `UITableview`, the `UIWebview` delgate method keeps get calling over and over. i am calling the webviewDidFinishLoad method to get the content height. Any kind of help/suggestion would be very appreciative.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canCollapseSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.restauRantMenuArray.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


    if ([self tableView:self.restaurantMenuTableView canCollapseSection:section])
    {
        if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section])
        {

            return  2; // return rows when expanded
        }

        return 1; // only top row showing
    }

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;


}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    if ([self tableView:self.restaurantMenuTableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"menuTitleCell";

            RestaurantMenuTitleTableViewCell *cell =(RestaurantMenuTitleTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[RestaurantMenuTitleTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
                NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RestaurantMenuTitleTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
            }


            RestaurantMenuItemObject *object = [self.restauRantMenuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

            cell.titleWebView.opaque = NO;

            cell.titleWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            [cell.titleWebView loadHTMLString:object.menuTitle baseURL:nil];

            cell.titleWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;


            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            return cell;

        }
        else
        {
            static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"menuContentCell";

            RestaurantMenuContentTableViewCell *cell =(RestaurantMenuContentTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[RestaurantMenuContentTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
                NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RestaurantMenuContentTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
            }



            RestaurantMenuItemObject *object = [self.restauRantMenuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];



            cell.contentWebView.tag = indexPath.section + 1000;

            cell.contentWebView.opaque = NO;

            cell.contentWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            [cell.contentWebView loadHTMLString:object.menuContent baseURL:nil];

            //cell.contentWebView.scrollView.delegate = self;

            [cell.contentWebView.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

           // cell.contentWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

            //cell.contentWebView.delegate = self;

            if([[self.imageHeightArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isEqualToString:@"150"])
            {
                //cell.contentWebView.delegate = self;
            }


            // first row
            //cell.textLabel.text = @"Expandable"; // only top row showing

            if ([expandedSections containsIndex:indexPath.section])
            {
                //cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];
            }
            else
            {
                //cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown]
            }

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            return cell;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        return cell;

    }

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RestaurantMenuItemObject *object = [self.restauRantMenuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    UIWebView *thisWebView = (UIWebView*)[self.restaurantMenuTableView viewWithTag:indexPath.section+1000];

    [thisWebView loadHTMLString:object.menuContent baseURL:nil];

    thisWebView.delegate = self;



    //[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    //if there is any previous selected index
    //if selected index is not the previous selected

    if (selectedIndex && (selectedIndex.section != indexPath.section)) {
        [self collapseOrExpandForIndexPath:selectedIndex inTableView:tableView];
    }


    if ([selectedIndex isEqual:indexPath]) {
        selectedIndex = nil;
    }
    else{
        selectedIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:indexPath.section];

    }


    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
    {
        [self collapseOrExpandForIndexPath:indexPath inTableView:tableView];
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
        }

    }

}

- (void)collapseOrExpandForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath inTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    if (!indexPath.row)
    {
        // only first row toggles exapand/collapse
        //[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

        NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
        BOOL currentlyExpanded = [expandedSections containsIndex:section];
        NSInteger rows;

        NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];

        if (currentlyExpanded)
        {
            rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
            [expandedSections removeIndex:section];

        }
        else
        {
            [expandedSections addIndex:section];
            rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
        }

        for (int i=1; i<rows; i++)
        {
            NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i
                                                           inSection:section];
            [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
        }


        if (currentlyExpanded)
        {
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];



        }
        else
        {

            //RestaurantMenuItemObject *object = [self.restauRantMenuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

//            UIWebView *thisWebView = (UIWebView*)[self.restaurantMenuTableView viewWithTag:indexPath.section+1000];
//            
//            [thisWebView loadHTMLString:object.menuContent baseURL:nil];
//            
//            thisWebView.delegate = self;

            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];


        }
    }

}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;


    if(indexPath.row == 0)
        return 50.00;
    else
    {
        return 240;//[[self.imageHeightArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] integerValue];
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1.00;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1.00;
}
```

## pragma mark Table View Delegate Method ends

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a class level property (CGFloat),say **webViewHeight** to track web view's height.
2. On table view didSelectRowAtIndexPath method load url in web view.
3. Calculate web view height in webviewDidFinishLoad delegate method of web view and set it in class level height variable,webViewHeight. After calculating height call [tableView reloadData];
4. Set selected cell height with webViewHeight and rest with default,say 44.0 in heightForRowAtIndexPath method of data source.

**IMP:** Set maximum web view height also if calculated height exceed max height set calculated height to max height. And enable web view scrolling so that user is able to view all web view content.

Comment: Its not working for me.. Can you please give me an example.

Comment: I also added my source code.. Can you please suggest me how should i proceed?